# jQuery Context Menu only appears on the first ten tr elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, contextmenu

---

On my webpage I am using this [Simple Context Menu Plugin](https://github.com/joewalnes/jquery-simple-context-menu) for showing a little contextmenu by rightclicking a table row in some html tables, who are made with [Datatables Plugin](http://www.datatables.net/).

Now to my question. The context menu appears on every table only by the first ten rows.
For me it doesn't seem that I made anything else in the first rows than in the rows after row ten.

Attached some code from my webpage:

A table example:

```
<table id="datatable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><thead><tr>      <th>ID</th><th>Vorname</th><th>Nachname</th><th>Kunde</th><th>Von</th><th>Bis</th><th>Weiterbildung</th><th>Ausbilder</th><th>Achievment</th><th>Beschreibung</th><th>Zertifikat</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="contextmenu"><td>11</td><td>Kraemer</td><td>Test</td><td>hjadfkjas</td><td>24.06.2014</td><td>24.06.2014</td><td>test hp</td><td>Test HP</td><td></td><td>TitelDesZertifikates</td><td>TestZertifikat</td></tr><tr class="contextmenu"><td>16</td><td>ölakdsjfölk</td><td>jfdaölfjd</td><td>fneionffoefneofef</td><td>25.06.2014</td><td>25.06.2014</td><td>test hp</td><td>Test HP</td><td></td><td>adf</td><td>TestZertifikat</td></tr><tr class="contextmenu"><td>18</td><td>adfadf</td><td>adfadsf</td><td>fneionffoefneofef</td><td>25.06.2014</td><td>25.06.2014</td><td>test hp</td><td>Test HP</td><td></td><td>Test</td><td>TestZertifikat</td></tr><tr class="contextmenu"><td>19</td><td>adfadsf</td><td>afdafd</td><td>fneionffoefneofef</td><td>25.06.2014</td><td>25.06.2014</td><td>test hp</td><td>Test HP</td><td></td><td></td><td>TestZertifikat</td></tr><tr class="contextmenu"><td>20</td><td>adfadsf</td><td>Test</td><td>fneionffoefneofef</td><td>25.06.2014</td><td>25.06.2014</td><td>test hp</td><td>Test HP</td><td></td><td></td><td>TestZertifikat</td></tr><tr class="contextmenu"><td>21</td><td>adfadsf</td><td>Test</td><td>fneionffoefneofef</td><td>25.06.2014</td><td>25.06.2014</td><td>test hp</td><td>Test HP</td><td></td><td></td><td>TestZertifikat</td></tr><tr class="contextmenu"><td>22</td><td>jflajslfökj</td><td>sjdflsdkjfl</td><td>hjadfkjas</td><td>25.06.2014</td><td>25.06.2014</td><td>test hp</td><td>Name</td><td></td><td></td><td>TelefonZertifikat</td></tr><tr class="contextmenu"><td>23</td><td>Luger</td><td>Christian</td><td>hjadfkjas</td><td>26.06.2014</td><td>30.06.2014</td><td>aslökdfj</td><td>Name</td><td></td><td></td><td>TitelDesZertifikates</td></tr><tr class="contextmenu"><td>24</td><td>Meier</td><td>Hans</td><td>EPC</td><td>02.06.2014</td><td>06.06.2014</td><td>test hp</td><td>Althammer Walter</td><td>teilgenommen</td><td>irgedwas</td><td>TestZertifikat</td></tr><tr class="contextmenu"><td>25</td><td>Krämer</td><td>Sebastian</td><td>hjadfkjas</td><td>07.07.2014</td><td>07.07.2014</td><td>aslökdfj</td><td>Althammer Walter</td><td>Test</td><td>Test</td><td>Bachmann Basic Training</td></tr><tr class="contextmenu"><td>27</td><td>Kraemer</td><td>Sebastian</td><td>EPC</td><td>07.07.2014</td><td>07.07.2014</td><td>Laser Grundlagen Teil 1</td><td>Althammer Walter</td><td></td><td></td><td>Bachmann Basic Training</td></tr><tr class="contextmenu"><td>28</td><td>ecececsececec</td><td>Krämer</td><td>EPC</td><td>09.07.2014</td><td>13.07.2014</td><td>Laser Grundlagen Teil 1</td><td>Althammer Walter</td><td></td><td></td><td>Bachmann Basic Training</td></tr><tr class="contextmenu"><td>29</td><td>Sebastian</td><td>Krämer</td><td>EPC</td><td>07.07.2014</td><td>07.07.2014</td><td>Laser Grundlagen Teil 1</td><td>Sebastian Krämer</td><td></td><td></td><td>Bachmann Basic Training</td></tr><tr class="contextmenu"><td>30</td><td>Sebastian</td><td>Krämer</td><td>EPC</td><td>08.07.2014</td><td>08.07.2014</td><td>Laser Grundlagen Teil 1</td><td>Althammer Walter</td><td></td><td></td><td>Bachmann Basic Training</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

The context menu:

```
 $(function() 
    {
        $('.contextmenu').contextPopup({
          title: 'Optionen',
          items: [
            {label:'Editieren', icon:'../resources/edit.ico', action:function() 
                {  
                var modalKind;

                switch(parseInt($.getUrlVar('submit')))
                {
                    case 0: 
                        modalKind = "modalParticipant";
                        break;
                    case 1: 
                        modalKind = "modalTrainer";
                        break;
                    case 2: 
                        modalKind = "modalTraining";
                        break;
                    case 3: 
                        modalKind = "modalCustomer";
                        break;
                    case 4: 
                        modalKind = "modalCertificate";
                        break;
                    case 5: 
                        modalKind = "modalPageUser";
                        break;
                    default: 
                        modalKind = "modalParticipant";
                        break;
                }

                //Create cookie to store selected datas
                $.cookie("dataTableInformation", modalKind + "||" + cookietext);
                fillModal();
                sortListsOfParticipantFormular();

                $('#'.concat(modalKind)).modal('show'); }
            },
                        {label:'Löschen', icon:'../resources/cross.png', action:function() {  addOrUpdateUrlParam("entryID", entryID);} }
                      ]
                    });
                });
```

The right click function:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#datatable').DataTable();

        $('#datatable tbody').on('mousedown', 'tr', function(e)
        {
            cookietext = "";
            switch(e.which)
            {
                case 3: entryID = $('td', this).eq(0).text();
                        $(this).find('td').each (function()
                        {
                            cookietext += $(this).text() + "||";
                        });
                     break;
            }
        });
    } );
```

Do anyone have an idea why the contextmenu don't appear?

After trying some possibilities, now I have seen that with replacing some code by the context menu,
the context menu appears on all rows. The new code:

```
 $('.contextmenu').contextPopup({
          title: 'Optionen',
          items: [
            {label:'Editieren', icon:'../resources/edit.ico', action:function() 
                {  
                var modalKind;

                switch(parseInt($.getUrlVar('submit')))
                {
                    case 0: 
                        modalKind = "modalParticipant";
                        break;
                    case 1: 
                        modalKind = "modalTrainer";
                        break;
                    case 2: 
                        modalKind = "modalTraining";
                        break;
                    case 3: 
                        modalKind = "modalCustomer";
                        break;
                    case 4: 
                        modalKind = "modalCertificate";
                        break;
                    case 5: 
                        modalKind = "modalPageUser";
                        break;
                    default: 
                        modalKind = "modalParticipant";
                        break;
                }

                //Create cookie to store selected datas
                $.cookie("dataTableInformation", modalKind + "||" + cookietext);
                fillModal();

                $('#'.concat(modalKind)).modal('show'); }
            },
                        {label:'Löschen', icon:'../resources/cross.png', action:function() {  addOrUpdateUrlParam("entryID", entryID);} }
                      ]
                    });
```

Does anyone know why the new code attaches the context menu to all rows and the old only to the first ten?

Comment: Can you try and make JSFiddle for this?

Comment: I don't think that JSFiddle is right for this because I also use some PHP code in the webpage. Do you know a good JSFiddle alternative with PHP?

Comment: Try to remove that part of code which contains PHP or some images or other dependent sources. Post that code which can give us HTML markup and JS associated with it...

Comment: Ok. Now i have tried to store the code on JSFiddle [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/UhLCn/3/).